# Make random curvy lines or segments for paths on Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, paperjs

Here is the code that I tried:

```
var myPath = new Path();
myPath.strokeColor = 'red';
myPath.strokeWidth = 5;
myPath.dashArray = [20, 5];
myPath.add(new Point(1800, 120));

function onFrame(event) {
    if(event.count%10 == 0) {
        var angle = Math.random(0, 1)*Math.PI;
        var all_points = myPath.segments.length;
        var last_point = myPath.segments[all_points - 1];
        myPath.add(new Point(last_point.point.x + 40*Math.cos(angle*(180 / Math.PI)), last_point.point.y + 40*Math.sin(angle*(180 / Math.PI))));
        myPath.smooth({type: 'geometric', factor: 2});
    }
}
```

I was thinking this would choose a random angle between 0 and Math.PI and then plot the points from the last point. However, it just draws a line at 45 degree going back and forth. I did a `console.log()` for the angle and it is always something random between 0 and Math.PI.

I want to achieve something similar to this: https://codepen.io/speaud/pen/ExxzrL

Here is what I have [so far](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.15/S/dVJRa4MwGPwrH8Iwds5pWWFY+jAGgz0MCnvYQy0jS1KV6peSpN2k+N8XjUNZt5eQfHeXu4uePaS18FLvdS8MK7zQY5J35xNVUDdragpYAYpP6LYkWGboppE2Su7Fo6yksgxfCe7/Bt9K3ssXI8CpLh6Uoo0db+ZxCIvtCFLOSW8lSzRkHlvYLkFnmuHuiMyUEkHik7KZiTgJNAGcLWjKnTtGTB7RXCUxrFYQD2BmujIU80pY15fOSVHksibWIAlm/WT9vJxwq+r90IXQVvBTSeS1ddBRJTA3xYRdUW0c/ZK9mVx1A8l2kP1ZeLwncusXXMNd7PIxqUlfYUaS+xhuYUgdBCFcCJuJUJf4j9A97JhG11Lab3w2zUGk4OdC1sKokvkh7CgzUqUwb52mzbC1/8qHEnTv2nnpZtt+Aw==). My idea was to get a random angle and then gets sin and cosine values for that angle and add them to the last point in the path. This would move the path randomly in a certain direction.

I was hoping that it would create nice curvy non-intersecting paths but the path goes over the same place multiple times also making it smooth with the `smooth()` function changes its previous course a little.

Comment: Could you try to describe the algorithm that you have in mind and try to achieve, with simple words even maybe illustrating it ?

Comment: Hi @sasensi I have created a sketch and posted link to it in the question. :)

Comment: Ok, now I think that I better understand what you're trying to achieve. If you really want to have a smooth output, I think that Paper.js is maybe not the way to go as it deals with vector graphics and you would have to create a path with a lot of point to achieve your desired result (which would be memory consuming). I think that using the Canvas API directly and switch from raw random number to something like Perlin noise can greatly help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ikwNrFvnL3g

Answer (score 0):

`Math.cos` and `Math.sin` get angle in radians but in your code you convert them to degrees

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand how that would affect anything. :)